# git pull not changing anything

Tags: git, eclipse

I switched my branch to gg branch `git checkout gg && git pull` but when I go back to eclipse nothing changed, I tried git `reset --hard gg` but still nothing changed

Comment: In the _Git Staging_ or _Git Repositories_ view click the _Refresh_ button for that repository.

Comment: Maybe the two branches points the exactly same commit. Can you give us more details for example; output of ```git log --oneline --graph --all``` and ```git branch -vv```

Answer (score 0):

**Synchronize** your project after taking the pull.

Comment: how can I do Synchronize  ?

Comment: Right click on project -> Team -> Synchronize